# Quick Way to Convert Existing CSS Layout to IE4 Friendly?

Tags: css, visual-studio, internet-explorer, browser

The  built-in WebBrowser Control in Visual Studio apparently only supports up to IE4. When wrapping your typical jQuery/jQuery-UI, some layout errors abound. Is there an easy way to convert the webpage's layout to IE4 friendly (I'd imagine, table-structure rather than div-based etc)?

Comment: IE4? Are you serious? The browser from 1997? The one which had less than 1% browser share 6 years ago?

Comment: This must be a mistake. You mean IE6, right? And even that would be atrocious. You may need a new Web Browser control, or a new version of Visual Studio.

Comment: But really... don't even think about it. The IE4 binaries aren't even available online anymore, and won't run on anything older than... erm... 95?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HELP! Site not rendering in IE3!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515933/help-site-not-rendering-in-ie3)

Answer (score 3):

No. (It's not going to be easy. Or quick.)